# Вывод данных у определенной записи

Tags: mysqli, php

Подскажите, как сделать какую-либо операцию с определенной записью, когда все они выведены.  Т.е в данном случае, например, если мы выключили то у записи под ID 1 обновилось поле status, это пример. Подробнее на скриншоте.

P.S. не обращайте внимание на поля)  [image: modules]

Comment: where id = 1 не ?

Comment: а как мы узнаем на какую из них кнопку нажали ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно такая байда делается с помощью дата-атрибутов: в html-атрибуты пихаются айдишники записей, и потом по ним ищется нужный элемент. Формально атрибут могут быть любыми, но настоящий программист использует для этого только атрибуты с префиксом `data-`. Итак, получается следующий результат:

```
<div class="row" data-item-id="1">
//stuff
    <div class="status text-muted">Выключено</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Включить</button>
</div>
```

После этого, получая ответ сервера типа `{"updated":[{"id":1,"status":"Включено"}]}`, можно легко найти нужный итем по селектору '[data-item-id="' + updatedRecord.id + '"]', найти в нем элемент `.status` и обновить его новыми данными. Можно даже сделать шаг вперед и отметить свойства итема дата-атрибутами:

```
<div class="status text-muted" data-binded-property="status">Выключено</div>
```

После этого можно возвести обновление в автомат, когда движок будет сам искать и обновлять нужные элементы.

**Это что, все?**

Нет, конечно не все. Есть еще две разновидности пути: попроще и посложнее. Путь попроще заключается в том, что при создании аякс-запроса у нас гарантированно есть ссылка на элемент, который это затеял: кнопка "Включить". В этом случае мы можно просто пробежаться вверх по дерево до родительского элемента всего итема и спуститься вниз до нужного элемента, который можно обновить. Автоматизация никакая, но пишется в две *корявых* строчки и подходит для быстрого написания функционала.

Вариант посложнее уже виден из концовки ответа. Можно вывести автоматизацию на новый уровень - ввести MVC, сделать т.н. data-bindings, привязать ***модели*** к ***отображению***, сделать гибкую систему шаблонов (потому что рано или поздно все равно придется столкнуться с тем же списком, которым просто так элемент не обновишь) и внедрить какой-нибудь моднявый REST. Это затратный, но в то же время очень крутой вариант. Если интересно - посмотрите ember.js, например. Я в это так и не окунулся пока, но можно скинуть всю работу по обновлению на плечи фреймворка и спокойно заниматься насущными делами, не раздумывая о такой мелочи и не занимаясь повторением кода.

Comment: спасибо огромное за столь объемный ответ)) все понял буду действовать)